# How to line up lists side by side?

Tags: html, css

I am making a calendar and I have multiple lists that I want to place side-by-side.  I have a `div` and inside that `div` there are multiple lists.  Here is the html:

```
<div class="weekly-view">
    <ul class="hours">
        <li>
            <div class="appt">1</div>
            <div class="appt">1</div>
            <div class="appt">1</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="appt">2</div>
            <div class="appt">2</div>
            <div class="appt">2</div>
        </li>
        ....
    </ul>
    <ul class="hours">
        <li>
            <div class="appt">3</div>
            <div class="appt">3</div>
            <div class="appt">3</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="appt">4</div>
            <div class="appt">4</div>
            <div class="appt">4</div>
        </li>
        ....
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the css:

```
.weekly-view {
  clear: both;
  list-style: none;
}
.weekly-view .hours {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.weekly-view .hours li {
  width: 13.857142857%;
}
```

I am using `webkit` and keep getting a huge margin on the right side.  I can't figure it out where it is coming from.  How would I place these lists side by side?

Comment: Things that need to be side-by-side should have `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:top`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your css file should be this:

```
.weekly-view {
  clear: both;
  list-style: none;
}
.weekly-view .hours {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.weekly-view .hours li {
  width: 13.857142857%;
}
.hours {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="weekly-view">
  <div class="hours">
    <ul >
        <li>
            <div class="appt">1</div>
            <div class="appt">1</div>
            <div class="appt">1</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="appt">2</div>
            <div class="appt">2</div>
            <div class="appt">2</div>
        </li>
        ....
    </ul>
  </div> 
  <div class="hours">
    <ul >
        <li>
            <div class="appt">3</div>
            <div class="appt">3</div>
            <div class="appt">3</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="appt">4</div>
            <div class="appt">4</div>
            <div class="appt">4</div>
        </li>
        ....
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
   .hours{
        float: left;
        margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    }
ul, li{
margin:0;
padding:0 0 0 15px;    
}
```